# Methods for detecting vertical texts in an image using OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv, tesseract, google-cloud-vision

I want to detect text in containers such as this
[container with vertical texts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3WbU.jpg)

I tried OpenCV examples such as [textdetection.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp)

Those are capable of detecting horizontal text only. Is there other solutions than cloud vision ocr to address such situations.

Comment: You can rotate the image and look for horizontal text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use tesseract instead , as it has capability of reading text vertically align as well : 
Here is a sample code :

```
import Image
import pytesseract
# provide the cropped area with text
def GetOCR(tempFilepath,languages ='eng'):
    img = Image.open(tempFilepath)
    #img= img.convert('L')
    # filters can be applied optionally for reading the proper text from the image
    img.load()
    # -psm 5 will assume the text allinged vertically 
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang = languages,config='-psm 6')
    print "text :{0}".format(text)
```

Note : The above sample will work , provided you should have pytesseract module installed , and tesseract-ocr exe installed in your machine .
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I think I have to train tesseract to identify those text, is it possible to do it in Raspberry Pi

Comment: Yes, you can have your own training data  -It's a time taking process , but that may not apply to your scenario , You could get your result easily if you could apply some filters on your image . as in this case you are already getting 90+% accuracy