# Rekognition for numbers aligned vertically?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Rekognition does great with traditional horizontally aligned numbers but doesn't work well when numbers are vertically aligned (top to bottom).  Can anyone think of a way to use Rekognition for vertically aligned numbers?

I've tried cropping the image and rotating it, but with same poor results.

I use python but doesn't really matter since Rekognition is doing the work internally. [(see attached example, seems very clear to me and would work perfectly if numbers were aligned horizontally.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD8ky.jpg)

Comment: Not aware that Rekognition supports vertical text detection currently. I think you may want to use tesseract. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616809/methods-for-detecting-vertical-texts-in-an-image-using-opencv

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write some code that looks at the Bounding Boxes of the returned text and makes some assumptions of how they align.

For example:

- If the bounding boxes mostly overlap horizontally
- Sort them in order of the vertical position
- Confirm that the vertical spacing is within a given distance
- Concatenate them together into one string

**Update:** I tried putting your sample image into Rekognition and it didn't detect the numbers. However, when I cropped the image to a smaller section, it successfully detected the numbers. It also provided them back in "top-down" order.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful but I was amazed how cropped I had to get before it would detect them... fortunately the numbers I want to detect are located somewhat reliably relative to the text it can detect, so I'm going to play around with writing a cropping algorithm relative to other texts it finds... pain in the butt, but thank you for your help!